# May a 'ball' that has been 'cut off' still be called a 'ball'?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the metric subspace $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the metric defined in the usual sense, and the ball $B(0,1)$, defined to be the ball centred at $x=0$ with radius $1$.

Now since only the right half of the ball 'exists' within our subspace, then can we still say that the ball $B(0;1)$ exists?

Comment: Side note: sounds pretty harsh in its current form.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the word sphere, and therefore the answer is it's a hemisphere?

Comment: @Mazura Using centre $0$ and radius $1$, I imagine sphere ($S$) would fit the set $S(0,1)=\{x\in \Bbb{R} \mid |\,x\,|=1 \}$, rather than ball ($B$), which is $B(0,1)=\{x\in \Bbb{R} \mid |\,x\,|<1 \}$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd say so yes. The ball just denotes the set $B(0;1):=\{x\in X\mid d(0,x)\leq 1\}$. It has nothing to do with the geometric intuition one might have about balls

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in any metric space, you may define the ball of any center and radius.

In your example, the ball of center $0$ and radius $1$ in the metric space $[0,1]$ is $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 6):

I think expecting the same intuitive  result for open balls in different metric spaces isn't a good idea in general.

For example, take $\Bbb R$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise. Then $B(0,r)=\Bbb R$ if $r>1$ and $\{0\}$ if $r\leq 1$.

Of course it's quite unintuitive that what's in the ball doesn't depend on the radius except whether it is bigger or smaller than $1$. They're still the open balls in that space.

You can however expect to find the same open *sets* in two equivalent metrics, like $\Bbb R^2$ with $d_E$ the standard Euclidean metric and $d_\infty(x,y)=\max\{|x_1-y_1|, |x_2-y_2|\}$.

The Euclidean metric gives open balls that look like discs, and I believe that with $d_\infty$ they look like squares, but all of the open *sets* are the same.

Lastly if you took $(0,1)$ as a metric subspace of $\Bbb R$, you would have a ordinary open intervals as open balls. However the fact that some of the open balls are '*missing*' half of their usual elements could either be intuitively attributed to the fact that you're using a subspace hence missing elements, or in another way to the fact that you're now using a bounded metric space, so after some finite radius you get no new elements to an open ball.

Again though that intuition breaks down in other examples.

Comment: Another example of a metric where balls have counterintuitive shapes: let $d_E$ be the Euclidean distance function, and let $d(x,y) = d_E(x,y)$ IFF $d_E(x,y) \leq 1$ and $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2d_E(x,y)}$ otherwise. (This does in fact meet the requirements for a distance-function defining a metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$.) Then, for balls where $\frac{1}{2} < r < 1$, the shape of the ball is the entire space *minus* a "thick shell."

Comment: That's a very interesting example, thanks for that!

Comment: Thank you! I came up with it as part of a thesis paper on metric spaces I wrote in college. I was always kind of afraid I'd be the only person who found the concept of a continuously-decreasing distance-function interesting.